# "There has been an error processing your request" in Admin area after installation

Tags: magento2, error, installation

I'm trying to upgrade to Magento 2 and after completing the installation process and trying to log into the admin area, I get the following error:

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 393378540903

The error log shows the following:

> {"0":"Class Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config\SchemaLocator does not exist","1":"#0 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\\Backend...')\n#1 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\\Backend...')\n#2 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Backend...')\n#3 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Backend...')\n#4 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Backend...', NULL, 'configReader', 'Magento\\Backend...')\n#5 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Backend...', Array, Array)\n#6 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Backend...', Array, Array)\n#7 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Backend...')\n#8 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Backend...')\n#9 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Backend...', NULL, 'menuConfig', 'Magento\\Backend...')\n#10 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Backend...', Array, Array)\n#11 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Backend...', Array, Array)\n#12 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Backend...')\n#13 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Backend...')\n#14 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(230): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'url', 'Magento\\Backend...')\n#15 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Backend...', Array, Array)\n#16 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Backend...', Array, Array)\n#17 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Backend...', Array)\n#18 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/RouterList.php(51): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Backend...')\n#19 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/RouterList.php(65): Magento\Framework\App\RouterList->getRouterInstance('admin')\n#20 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\RouterList->current()\n#21 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#22 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#23 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#24 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#25 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#26 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#27 /home/wonder/public_html/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))\n#28 {main}","url":"/magento2/admin/","script_name":"/magento2/index.php"}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if relevant but I had Magento 2 installed but then wiped the directory and database, and then reinstalled in the same directory with a new database. It worked fine before but now has that error.